# Query doesn't work with WHERE AND only with WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

The single query for title works, but more than one song with the title exist. so the new query that includes artist doesn't work. ALthough EXACT search for the song title is correct and works with single query.

what am i doing wrong

```
            //$checkTitle = mysql_query("SELECT * from lyrics WHERE title = '$querytitle'");
            $checkTitle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE artist = '$queryArtist' AND title = '$queryTitle'");
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($checkTitle);
            if (!$checkTitle) {
                die('Query Failed');
            } 
            if ($result['title'] == $querytitle)  {
            ?><div id='message'>Song Titled Already Exist <?php echo $cleanTitle; ?> by Artist : <? echo $artist; ?></div><br><br><?
            } else {
            ?><div id="message">Song Titled : <?php echo $cleanTitle; ?> has been added to the database! - <a href="<?php echo $siteURL; ?>artist.php?aid=<?php echo $artist; ?>" target="_Blank">View Artist Page</a></div><br /><br /> <?php echo $queryArtist; ?><?
            print_r($result); // the data returned from the query
            }
```

Comment: looks like you should be doing the match in the db query

Comment: Why aren't you doing this in your SQL query?

Comment: why are you not doing this in a `where` clause in your query? Consider how horribly inefficient this is if you've got a million records, and the title you want is the LAST record in the database? you fetch 1,000,000 rows, and throw away 999,999. I don't know about you, but when I go for groceries, I only buy what I need. I don't buy the entire store, drive home, then throw away the entire inventory except the chocolate bar I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). Your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, the way to show your appreciation on this site is to click the up arrow next to the answer to mark it as a good answer, and pick one answer to mark as correct with the checkmark. Also, your new code will cause problems if two artists make a song with the same name (which happens all of the time).

Comment: always add `LIMIT 1` to the select query if you only want\expect 1 row. Otherwise the db searches every row even after it finds a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you never figured it out from the other question you posted. Try using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE artist = '$artist' AND title = '$queryTitle'
```

Then, if you are expecting only one result, you can use something like this to utilize it:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM lyrics WHERE artist = '$artist' AND title = '$queryTitle'";
$checkTitle = mysql_query($query);
// assuming you have one result:
$row = mysql_fetch_array($checkTitle)
if ($row['title'] == $querytitle) {
    echo "<div id='message'>Song Titled Already Exist $cleanTitle by Artist : $cleanTitle</div><br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from lyrics WHERE artist = '$artist' AND title = '$title'
```

.. or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mention, this is horribly inefficient, since the database can do this faster, and simpler:

```
SELECT * from lyrics WHERE artist = '$artist' AND title = '$queryTitle'
```

You can improve this even further by making sure you have an index on (artist, title).

Also, make sure you `mysql_real_escape_string` both `$artist` and `$queryTitle` before running this query to protect yourself from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).